# Sum matching items from grid

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a table of companies to pay, the amount to pay them via direct debit, then an adjacent grid of week numbers; then in another part of the sheet just a table of week numbers, how can I sum up the direct debits that are due on that week?

[image: List of companies to pay]

Then the desired result beneath might look like:

```
Week Numbers    |  Total Out
---------------------------------
1               |  655.81
2               |  0.00
3               |  0.00
4               |  0.00
5               |  4020.68
6               |  638.81
...and so on
```

I have tried a few combinations of SUMPRODUCT but I don't quite know enough about the formulae to reach a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$5)*($C$2:$H$5=$A9))
```

[image]